# how to add class to combobox and apply to picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In C# WinApp, how can I add image class (lowpass filter and highpass filter) to ComboBox,
and then apply to PictureBox? I did a search and usually, the answers are only shown text.

Do I have to convert class to string, and how do I apply it to PictureBox?
The PictureBox has an image so I want to apply lowpass filter to the image in PictureBox using Combobox

Comment: so you are wanting to apply the lowpass and highpass filter depending on which is selected in the drop down ? where is lowpass and highpass filter coming from ? I don't know alot about that

Comment: @MicahArmantrout yes, public class lowpassfilter and public class highpassfilter

Comment: If the class is overriding `ToString()` returning a speaking name, you can add an object of this class directly into the combobox without conversion. You can then get it back through `combobox.SelectedItem` and will have to cast it to some base class of the two filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple different ways

the first one would be without databinding

[MSDN Add/Remove items to dropdown WF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-items-from-a-wf-combobox?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Just call

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Low Pass"); 
comboBox1.Items.Add("High Pass");
```

on the [onload MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) event in windows forms

then on the [selectedindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) change event you handle what to do when one or the other is selected

you can do this by checking combobox1.text

```
if (combobox1.text == "High Pass")
{
  //apply filter
}
else if (combobox1.text == "High Pass")
{
  //apply filter
}
```

Something else you can look into is databinding [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Thanks you so much!! it's work @MicahArmantrout

Comment: Sweet can you accept my answer?